# shared preference in flutter - Check value if present or not?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to retrieve the data stored in shared preferences (User name  Password)
as I need to validate with the user entires -

I cant see in the documentation the code to retrieve the data stored

Answer (score 2):

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
String userName = prefs.getString("key_userName") ?? "_";
if (userName == "_")
  // this is a new user, no data found
else 
  // there exist a data in prefs
```

This is how you can retrieve the data in `SharedPreferences`.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code for retrieving of SharedPreferences value

```
RaisedButton retrieve = new RaisedButton(onPressed: () async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  if(prefs.get("userName") == null && prefs.get("password") == null) {
    // Data not available
  } else {
   // Data Available
    print("UserName: " + prefs.get("userName"));
    print("Password: " + prefs.get("password"));
  }
},
    child: new Text("Retrive"));
```

Also, refer:

https://github.com/jitsm555/flutter-login-screen